# Best way to Sync Mongo db (Server) with IOS Sqlite for chat App

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, chat

I am building an iPhone (native) chat app that uses `node.js` on `socket.io` , `Mongo db` (database) server side.

Now, I want to integrate the local database in the app. My question is which database will be best suited for this? I have many option to choose from (e.g. `SQLite`, `Core Data` , `Realm`).

Perhaps more importantly, what is the best way to sync my local database with the server-side database (i.e. `Mongo db`) for my chat application in iOS?

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: have you got any solutions?